# Python Random Number Generator within a normal distribution with Min and Max values

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, data-science, normal-distribution

In passing someone had suggested to me that I could use half normal distribution in python to set min and max points using 0 to infinity:
[halfnorm.rvs()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scipy-stats-halfnorm-python/)

The 0 seems to cut off the min, however I have no idea what to do with the infinity.

I would like to do a number generator from 0 - 15 within a normal distribution, but having a hard time finding a function that doesn't go over the max or below the min due to the nature of distribution limits.

Comment: I agree with you that a normal distribution per definition doesn't have a finite boundary, and then even the half normal distribution is not a normal distribution any more. Then the questions is really what you'd like to use it for.

Comment: I'm simulating a person's reaction times in sports where for example 0 would be instant.

Comment: So it doesn't have to be a normal distribution... Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions ... interesting .. I will have a look too.

Comment: Probability distribution of reaction times: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-Probability-distribution-of-reaction-times-aggregated-across-all-subjects-showing_fig2_5760738 It looks like lognormal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use the beta-distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution. It's quite simple (e.g. to integrate) and capable of fitting typical reaction time distributions.

Now the question is how to sample this efficiently for fixed α and β parameters ... `scipy` has done it for us: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html

**Edit**: Motivated by the comment and curiosity, here an example, plotting the histogram of 10 samples á 1000 values:

```
from scipy.stats import beta
from numpy import histogram
import pylab

max_time = 3
min_time = 0.5

a, b = 2, 7
dist = beta(a, b)

for _ in range(10):
    sample = min_time + dist.rvs(size=1000) * (max_time - min_time)
    his, bins = histogram(sample, bins=20, density=True)
    pylab.plot(bins[:-1], his, ".")
pylab.xlabel("Reaction time [s]")
pylab.ylabel("Probability density [1/s]")
pylab.grid()
pylab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I will try to create a reprex in python using the min and maxes from the original question, unless you or someone else beats me to it lol.

Comment: To keep your answer I won't put another answer with code (feel free to put a REPREX though). I did find that the distribution was much better and can be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had just answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69949203/4601890). I'll copy answer here as I think this question title is much more informative:

You can use uniform distribution with boundaries "translated" from normal to uniform space (using error function) and convert it to normal distribution using inverse error function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

mean = 0
std = 7
min_value = 0
max_value = 15

min_in_standard_domain = (min_value - mean) / std
max_in_standard_domain = (max_value - mean) / std

min_in_erf_domain = special.erf(min_in_standard_domain)
max_in_erf_domain = special.erf(max_in_standard_domain)

random_uniform_data = np.random.uniform(min_in_erf_domain, max_in_erf_domain, 10000)
random_gaussianized_data = (special.erfinv(random_uniform_data) * std) + mean
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
axes[0].hist(random_uniform_data, 30)
axes[1].hist(random_gaussianized_data, 30)
axes[0].set_title('uniform distribution samples')
axes[1].set_title('erfinv(uniform distribution samples)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I recently ran in to a similar issue.

To get around this and keep my min/max in reasonable bounds I just created some if statements to catch any numbers that went above the real min and max.

```
if value <0:
    value = abs(value)
elif value >15:
    value - 15 = diff
    value = 15-diff
```

This was close enough for me.