# Use mean, min, max and stddev to create 2D dataset

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, statistics

I am trying to create a 2d array that has a specific min, max, mean and stddev. Long story short I am trying to use both

```
np.random.randint(min,max, size=(row,col)
np.random.normal(mu,sigma, size=(row,col)
```

at the same time. Does anyone know if a function has already been made for this? I've have a standard deviation matching function but it changes the min and max of the array as well unfortunately that could be another way to do it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use uniform distribution with boundaries "translated" from normal to uniform space (using [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)) and convert it to normal distribution using inverse error function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

mean = 2
std = 3
min_value = 0
max_value = 6

min_in_standard_domain = (min_value - mean) / std  
max_in_standard_domain = (max_value - mean) / std

min_in_erf_domain = special.erf(min_in_standard_domain)
max_in_erf_domain = special.erf(max_in_standard_domain)

random_uniform_data = np.random.uniform(min_in_erf_domain, max_in_erf_domain, 10000)
random_gaussianized_data = (special.erfinv(random_uniform_data) * std) + mean
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
axes[0].hist(random_uniform_data, 30)
axes[1].hist(random_gaussianized_data, 30)
axes[0].set_title('uniform distribution samples')
axes[1].set_title('erfinv(uniform distribution samples)')
plt.show()
```

[image]